# Call By reference using Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm so new to c++, and i've just started doing pointers so when i'm using call by reference using pointers one thing i cant understand when i'm passing the addresses of the values , it works as it should be

```
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
}

int main(){
    int x=5 , y=10;
    swap(&x , &y);
    std::cout<<"The value of x is "<<x<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The value of y is "<<y<<std::endl;
}
```

but when i'm passing the values not the addresses it still works how?

```
int main(){
    int x=5 , y=10;
    swap(x , y);
    std::cout<<"The value of x is "<<x<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"The value of y is "<<y<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Next time round, do paste up the `#include`s too; actually the whole program, abridged to demonstrate the issue. Then we can be more certain about the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This shouldn't compile, you can't pass an `int` to an `int*`. What likely happened is, you have a

```
using namespace std;
```

statement at the start, and **`swap(x, y)` is actually calling [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)**. Get rid of the using statement and it should correctly fail to compile.

---

There are many pitfalls that come by using the namespace, read more about it on [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thanks man .... i knew that was a bad practise but didn't know there is a swap function in the standard library

Comment: Nice answer! @py300: As a rule of thumb, every useful function is in the standard library.